# How to fetch Data from VF Page to create a Report Type in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have an VF page which displays the number of days taken by some process using the date formula fields which are available in custom objects.

How can I display that days in report type using custom reports?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom formula Number field which will calculate TODAY-PROCESS START DATE.
You can use this field in reports as well.

Ash

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the date values into some custom field and create custom report type, and include that field in the report type